# Height issue with ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and I have set the textarea size correctly via code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                    width: 468,
                    height: 132
                } );
```

I have also deactivated the resizing correctly with code:
`config.resize_enabled = false;`

My problem is that the textarea's height still allows for text to be typed and the textarea expands vertically. I want the textarea to be set via a certain height and not move past that. So no more text can be entered once the height has been met.

Comment: What is your editor version and configuration? Are you not using plugins such as [Auto Grow](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/autogrow.html)? The behavior that you describe is not the default CKEditor behavior, so check your config.
See also other [Editor Size](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/size.html) samples, you can get the exact source code that produces them at the bottom of each CKEditor SDK page, so get it and compare with yours.